# Angular 2: Checkbox label printed on new line

Tags: angular

In this segment of code, the check box and the label are not appearing on the same line as is normal. Instead the checkbox is printed on one line and the label is printed on a new line. How do I get both to print on the same line?

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-2 sidenav">      
  <form>
    <h4><b>Brand</b></h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div *ngFor="let brand of brands">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="brand.name" 
          [(ngModel)]="brand.checked" (change)="filterProducts()"
          class="form-control inpcheck"> {{brand.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Resulting html from the console:

```
<div _ngcontent-c5="">
<label _ngcontent-c5="">
        <input _ngcontent-c5="" 
        class="form-control inpcheck ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
        name="brand.name" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="brand.name" 
        ng-reflect-model="false"> Whirlpool
        </label>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c5="">
<label _ngcontent-c5="">
        <input _ngcontent-c5="" 
        class="form-control inpcheck ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
        name="brand.name" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="brand.name" 
        ng-reflect-model="false"> KitchenAid
        </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't imagine this to be related to Angular in any way. I'm sure this is a pure CSS issue. Can you please post the resulting HTML from the browsers dev console?

Comment: I think this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469256/how-to-force-a-checkbox-and-text-on-the-same-line. One of these answers might also work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321795/how-to-align-the-checkbox-and-label-in-same-line-in-html

Comment: Gunther, I have post the resulting html.

Comment: See my previous comment.